# Azure DevOps server 2019 Migration to Azure DevOps services using Data Migration tool

Tags: azure-active-directory, data-migration, azure-devops-server-2019

following the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#identity-map-log) for migration .... but in our case all user identities are maintained in **Azure active directory** and **Azure ADDS**(no on-premise AD is used).... so can i **ignore** the status of users in identityMap.csv file and go ahead with migration? will this impact post import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important that you review the generated mapping file for completeness and correctness.

It says in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#identity-map-log) that once imported as a historical identity, there is no way to move that identity to become active. And Historical Identities do NOT have access to an organization after migration, do NOT have a licenses, and do NOT show up as a user in the organization.

So you'd better check the status of users in identityMap.csv file, especially those status are **historical** to make sure users' status are all correct.